# Canvas drawImage by points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to use `canvas.drawImage` but supplying dest and source x/y co-ordinates, rather than sizes?

Similar to how Java's drawImage works?

```
boolean Graphics.drawImage(Image img,
   int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2,
   int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2,
   ImageObserver observer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as with the other answers:

```
drawImage(image,   srcX, srcY, srcW, srcH,   dstX, dstY, dstW, dstH);
```

So in this case you would have to reverse the order of destination and source as well as calculating the *width* and *height*:

```
boolean Graphics.drawImage(Image img,
   int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2,
   int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2,
   ImageObserver observer);
```

Will become:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, srcx1, srcy1, srcx2 - srcx1, srcy2 - srcy1,
                   dstx1, dsty1, dstx2 - dstx1, dsty2 - dsty1);
```

or as a wrapper function, parameter-compatible with the Java version:

```
function drawImage(img, dstx1, dsty1, dstx2, dsty2, srcx1, srcy1, srcx2, srcy2) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, srcx1, srcy1, srcx2-srcx1, srcy2-srcy1,
                       dstx1, dsty1, dstx2-dstx1, dsty2-dsty1);
}
```

Width and height of 0 is invalid, source must be inside the source image boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Canvas has 3 valid ways to use draw image. Destination `x,y`, destination `x,y`, `width` and `height`, and those same, plus source `x,y`, `width` and `height`.

So you can do any of the following:

```
drawImage(image, dx, dy)
drawImage(image, dx, dy, dw, dh)
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)
```

Where `s...` is *source* and `d...` is *destination* x, y, width and height.

Visual example from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#drawing-images-to-the-canvas):

[image]